# Binding Command inside DataTemplate in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a button tag inside my data template. I want to trigger the command once I click on the button. If the button is outside of the data template my button is able to work. I tried few solutions such as :

```
<Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Update" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="btnUpdate_Click" 
                                    Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.updateProductionLineConfigCommand, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
```

This is my ViewModel:

```
public UpdateProductionLineConfigCommand updateProductionLineConfigCommand { get; set; }

    public ProductionLineConfigViewModel()
    {
        ProductionLineConfig = new ProductionLineConfig();
        newProductionLineConfigCommand = new NewProductionLineConfigCommand(this);
        updateProductionLineConfigCommand = new UpdateProductionLineConfigCommand(this);
    }
```

This is my Command class:

```
 public ProductionLineConfigViewModel VM { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public UpdateProductionLineConfigCommand(ProductionLineConfigViewModel vm)
    {
        VM = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        VM.updateProductionLineConfig();

    }
```

Can someone please help me on this. Why i am not able to bind my commands to my button?

Comment: What errors do you get? Did you run this in debug mode and watched the output window? There you can see binding error messages.

Comment: No error messages being shown. Unless i Remove the DataContext and just type in like this `Command="{Binding Path=updateProductionLineConfigCommand, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}`
`

Comment: Then I am getting message as : `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'updateProductionLineConfigCommand' property not found on 'object' ''DataGrid' (Name='productionLineConfigDataGrid')'. BindingExpression:Path=updateProductionLineConfigCommand; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='productionLineConfigDataGrid'); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnUpdate'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

Comment: @ChristianMurschall yes I am sure its DataGrid.

Comment: So it seems `updateProductionLineConfigCommand` is not really found in the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`. Maybe it helps to configure the trace level to see more detailed binding messages in the output window. See https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/

Comment: @RenéVogt is it because of 

`<Window.DataContext>
        <vm:ProductionLineConfigViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>`

Comment: @RenéVogt in my datagrid I didnt include any DataContext property

Comment: But the `DataContext` should be inherited down to the `DataGrid`, so this should be no problem. But to be sure, you can try Christian's suggestion and use `Window` as the ancestor to find. It doesn't make a difference if the window and the datagrid should have the same `DataContext` anyway.

Comment: I tried changing the DataGrid to Window, but now no error messages but  the command is not being triggered

Comment: @RenéVogt this is the current error message if i remove the DataContext and replace the xType to Window 
`System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'updateProductionLineConfigCommand' property not found on 'object' ''production_line_config_home' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=updateProductionLineConfigCommand; DataItem='production_line_config_home' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name='btnUpdate'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')`

Comment: If the relative source is found, it's a `DataGrid` (or a `Window` in your last version), so of course `Path` needs to be `DataContext.updateProductionLineConfigCommand`, because there is no `DataGrid.updateProduction...`. Sorry that I can't help more, it should work or produce an error debug message.

Comment: Perhaps the xaml editor can help: Select the Button -> Tap F4 (open properties)-> look for Command -> Click little button after the text box, select Create Binding -> from the binding window select your Command

Comment: How are you setting the `ControlTemplate` of the Button?

Comment: @ChristianMurschall I cant look for my command in the binding window.

Comment: How is your DataTemplate used, i.e. where it is applied?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution which fixed my problem.

```
<Button x:Name="btnUpdate" Content="Update" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
Click="btnUpdate_Click" Command="{Binding DataContext.updateProductionLineConfigCommand, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:production_line_config_home}}}"/>
```